# Flutter : Not getting code while Instagram login (Instagram login not working)

Tags: flutter, instagram, instagram-api, flutterwebviewplugin

I am using flutter and I want to achieve log in with Instagram in my app.
So I am following this [tutorial](https://developer-journey.com/2018/02/23/instagram-authentication-with-flutter/) for Instagram login,

I am getting success to log in but not getting user details, it is opening **Redirect URI** (https://www.google.com/) and not getting the code and access token.

Please help me if you know anything.

> Note: I am using **flutter_webview_plugin** for load webview in
>   flutter.

Here is the code which is opening webview for **Instagram login** ->

My log *print("Code ========== Code");* is not going to print anymore

```
  Future<Token> getToken(String appId, String appSecret) async {

  Stream<String> onCode = await _server();
  print("_server ========== _server");
  String url =
      "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/&response_type=code";
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url);
  final String code = await onCode.first;
  print("Code ========== Code");
  print("Code -> "+code);
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
      body: {"client_id": appId, "redirect_uri": "https://www.google.com/", "client_secret": appSecret,
      "code": code, "grant_type": "authorization_code"});

  flutterWebviewPlugin.close();


  return new Token.fromMap(json.decode(response.body));
}

Future<Stream<String>> _server() async {
  final StreamController<String> onCode = new StreamController();
  HttpServer server =
  await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 8585);
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
    final String code = request.uri.queryParameters["code"];
    request.response
      ..statusCode = 200
      ..headers.set("Content-Type", ContentType.HTML.mimeType)
      ..write("<html><h1>You can now close this window</h1></html>");
    await request.response.close();
    await server.close(force: true);
    onCode.add(code);
    await onCode.close();
  });
  return onCode.stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS configuration if anyone looking, add the code below to Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost:8585</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer actually, [This blog](https://developer-journey.com/2018/02/23/instagram-authentication-with-flutter/) was right,

My mistake is changing **Redirect URI**

so i have change **Redirect URI** https://www.google.com/ to **http://localhost:8585** and instagram login works.

```
Use http://localhost:8585 this Redirect URI for Instagram login
```

Comment: No. I have not checked in ios